# Is advanced notification the right term to use?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

If someone visit you or your company without notification prior to the visit, what is the right term to use?

e.g. someone visit the office without ***advanced notification***?

Please help me think of the adjective to use - preferred one word only.

Much appreciated.

Comment: I think the term you're thinking of is "advance notice".

Comment: “Advance**d** notification” would refer to using the latest technology or processes. It doesn’t say you’ll be notified in advance.

Comment: @Hearth Actually, *advance* and *notice* mean the same! However, "advance notification" as a set phrase is common, especially in bureaucratic jargon.

Comment: @Kris [advance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advance), [notice](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notice)... how do they "mean the same"? (I'm guessing you mean that _notice_ must come in _advance_.)

Comment: @tmgr Of course, yes.

Comment: @Hearth yes, advance notice is the right term. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word **prior**, as in

> He visited the office without prior notification.

Should you want to use advanced, you could say

> He visited the office without notifying in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I would say 'prenotification'.
Here is an example from Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:
'provided customers with written prenotification of the policy changes'.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this makes sense.'Prenotification is the notice that is given or served prior to a specific date; advance notice.'